# Maven exec:java -Xverify=none, profiler

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, profiler

I seem to be unable to get the `-Xverify:none` to be effective in `mvn exec:java`.

This is what I tried in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>my.cool.Main</mainClass>
                        <commandlineArgs>-keep-running</commandlineArgs>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-Xverify:none</argument>
                        </arguments>                        
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

But it is not effective (I cannot properly attach a profiler, it keeps giving me `Profiler Agent Warning: Retransform failed with status 62`)

How can I pass the `-X` so that it does work.

Comment: It is a JVM argument. You must invoke a new Jvm for that to be able to have any effect.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way of setting up the maven-exec-plugin to that I end up with a JVM with the -X setting?

Comment: "exec:java" runs inside the current jvm.  You should experiment with "exec:exec", in other words change the goal.